# Custom files in luminus

Tags: clojure, luminus

Where should I use put code files I write myself in a Clojure luminus application? And how can I export a function from it and import it to another file? Say, I've create a file "helper1.clj", how can I access the functions from it in "src/clj/my_app/routes/home.clj"? And where should I put the file "helper1.clj"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `project.clj` file.  You will see a line that reads:

```
:source-paths ["src/clj"]
```

This means that the `src/clj` directory will be the root of all namespaces.  The namespace is the directory path separated by dots, with the final portion of the namespace being the file name.  An example:

```
File name:                 my_app/src/clj/dirone/dirtwo/myfile.clj
Namespace in this file:    (ns dirone.dirtwo.myfile ...)
```

With that now established:  you should probably put new files in `src/clj/my_app` for now.  The namespace for `helper.clj` would then look like:

```
(ns my-app.helper ...)
```

You can create new directories under `src/clj`, for example, `src/clj/newdir`.  A file in that directory called `anotherfile.clj` would have a namespace of:

```
(ns newdir.anotherfile ...)
```

Look in your `my_app/routes/home.clj` file and look at the top, and you will see where `:require [my-app.layout :as layout]`.  You would add the following to reference your function `myfunc` in your file `helper.clj`:

```
;... list of items under :require
[my-app.helper :as h]
;...

(def something (h/myfunc ...))
```